# Use of KsqlDB as a HIstorian DB

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, historian

I want to make a historian database that records and retrieves data from Kafka topics to a permanent database.

I am trying to use the KsqlDB to do it, I have trying to use tables and streams from ksql but it disappears with the death of Kafka topics (extension of the retention period).
My question is "is it possible to use ksqldb as a historian for kafka? " Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your use of the word "historian"? I'm not clear what it means in this context.

Comment: I mean by historian, a software program that records and retrieves production and process data by time. As Kafka data is not permanent (retention), I need to create this historian ( history ).

Answer (score 1):

Kafka data certainly can be permanent (log.retention.ms=-1 or cleanup.policy=compact), although you don't need ksqlDB to make it so. By default, a table should be indefinitely available as it would be backed by a compacted Kafka topic

Anecdotally, the New York Times stores all their articles in a singly partitioned Kafka topic to sort their articles by time.

Note that ksqlDB is a processing engine built on Kafka Streams. It's not a database.

Comment: I understand, but Kafka is designed to be a near real-time tool, it has to be light and fast, even it's possible to handle an infinite amount of data. I think that I have to save the kafka content to an external database. Thank you.

Comment: KTables are light and fast. I suggest spending more time on CDC and Event Sourcing patterns rather than falling back into your traditional databases. Of course you can offload Kafka topics in real-time to places where it makes sense to do so (e.g. a search index), but if the intention is to simply select historical contents by a time window, you definitely don't need a database